# Create a database for init,insert,delete,median

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, median, avl-tree

I need to create a data base that works in this time complexity:

1. Init O(1)
2. Insert O(logn)
3. Delete O(logn)
4. Find Median O(1)

I'm struggling with finding the median in O(1).

I create an empty AVL Tree, and 1., 2. ,3. works like a charm with the needed time complexity. I thought about holding a pointer to the median everytime I input to the tree, but when I delete a node, how can I find the median in logn in the tree? because I believe I can't. It'll take about O(n) time complexity. Which means 3. won't work with O(logn) complexity after updating the pointer to find the new median.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think a binary tree with subtree sizes at each node satisfies this requirement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So every node will have a field called 'size', and then the n/2 value node will be the median?

Comment: I believe that a pair of balanced binary min/max heaps containing half the set each such that the median is the top of the larger heap or average of both, with back-pointers for deletion, ought to do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for this problem, based on what you already have:

1. [Order Statistics tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree), which is a variant of a binary search tree that allows you fast (logarithmic time) access to an element by its order statistic. In your case, you are looking for the `ceil(n/2)`'th element.

   While this mean you will find median in `O(logn)`, you can easily cache it after each insertion/deletion, and it won't change the complexity of the original operation - which will remain `O(logn)`.
2. Another (probably simpler) approach is to use the following observation:

   After each insertion/deletion of non empty set, the median can do one of the three options:

   a. Stay the same element. Example: `1,2,3 -> 1,2,3,4` - median is still 2,

   b. Move one element to the right. Example: `1,2,3,4 -> 1,2,3,4,5` - median changed from 2 to 3

   c. Move one element to the left. Example: `1,2,3,4,5 -> 1,2,3,4` (same as before, in reverse).

Assuming you can find in logarithimic time the "previous" and "next" elements, it is easy to maintain a pointer to the median with very little extra work required.

Comment: I used Minimum and Maximum heaps.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Minimum and maximum heaps do not support fast deletion (without more work to support it). Also, you should not accept the answer if you found something else more useful. It is fine to answer your own question (and accept it) if you had a different solution.